# My app skips starting an intent and executes the next code lines?

Tags: java, android

So I have the following currently:

```
public void addProject(View v) {
    String pn = "";
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    Intent i = new Intent(mMainContext, AddProject.class);
    mMainContext.startActivity(i, extras);

    if(extras.getString("projectName") != null) {
        pn = extras.getString("projectName");
    }
}
```

This is just an example, the first bit is correct though the if statement may not be but this isn't about that block.

What I have noticed is that if I place breakpoints on the new intent, start activity and then the if statement,

Android seems to skip past the startActivity and go onto the if statement.

If I then remove the if statement and run it again, it then launches the intent.

So what I've realised is that it runs to the end of the addProject block and then actually launches the intent...

Why is this? And more importantly, how I do stop it doing that?

Intended outcome is as follows:

1) user presses "Add Project" button
2) intent launched and user inputs project name and presses submit
3) calling intent then receives the p name for use later in the function.

Comment: you mean when you click the addProject button, it did not intent to AddProject?

Comment: Look at this documentation about how to start an activity and get a result back.  It doesn't work quite the way your thinking-- the activity won't be started as if you are calling a procedure.  See: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this?

`startActivity()` is asynchronous. When it returns, the activity is not yet started.

> how I do stop it doing that?

You can't.

> Intended outcome is as follows: 1) user presses "Add Project" button 2) intent launched and user inputs project name and presses submit 3) calling intent then receives the p name for use later in the function.

Having separate activities may not be the best plan for this (compared with using fragments).

If you wish to use activities, the most natural approach is:

- Use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`
- Have `AddProject` use `setResult()` to create a result `Intent` to deliver back to your first activity
- Have your first activity override `onActivityResult()`, where it can receive a copy of that result `Intent` and get the results from it

Note that this still will all happen after `addProject()` returns. However, you will (eventually) get your results.

The Android documentation does not cover this very well, but [this is what it has on the subject](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#StartingActivities).

Answer (score 0):

you must use onActivityResult for such task.

- From your main Activity use: startActivityForResults(intent) in place
  of startActivity();
- In your AddProject Activity when user inputs project name and press the
  button .

  Intent i = new Intent();
      i.putExtra("projectName",userInputTextFromEditText);
      setResults(RESULT_OK,i)
- In your MainActivity

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    pn = intent.getExtras.getStringExtra("projectName","");
  }

this way you will find your result